# When build an app project, Xcode can't find the other framework-project's 3rd-party swift package

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a xcworkspace where contains 2 projects

1. MyLib is a xcframework project

- In [Package Dependencies], it depends on Kingfisher

2. MyApp is an app project

- In [Package Dependencies], it depends on Firebase
- In [Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content], it has MyLib.framework with Embed & Sign.

If I build MyLib, the build is successful.

If I build MyApp, xcode first builds MyLib, and fails on "module Kingfisher is not found". How can I fix this problem???

In fact, I manage my projects with cocoapod. Now, I want to migrate them to SPM. This is the way I figure out to manage my projects with Xcode. If there is a better way to do, please tell me.

Thank you in advanced.